# How to find number of elements in an array which has one of its element as zero

Tags: c, arrays

I have declared an array of 30 elements as:-

```
unsigned char some_array[30];
```

I store some elements in the array, for eg:-

```
{0xFB, 0x07, 0x0B, 0x02, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x03, 0x08, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x07, 0x0A, 0x09, 0x06, 0x0D}
```

I need to find the number of elements in this array.

```
sizeof (some_array) / sizeof (some_array[0]);
```

yields 30, which is the total number of elements the array can store.

```
strlen(some_array);
```

yields 4, which is the index of 0x00 element in the array.

How can i determine the number of elements stored in the array ??

Comment: If you have `type arr[N]` you have an array of `N` `type`s. What do you mean find out how many elements are stored in the array?

Comment: In the above case, i am expecting the answer to be 15.

Comment: You need to define "not an element" in your question, because an array of 30 `unsigned char` will always have 30 elements (`unsigned char`s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before assigning the actual values, you can do a `memset` on the entire array which would set a value you are sure won't be part of your initialized range of values, example 0xff. Then do a `for` loop and count.

```
int cnt = 0;
memset (some_array, 0xff, 30);

for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    if (some_array[i] != 0xff) {
        cnt++;
    }
}

printf ("%d\n", cnt);
```

Comment: Yes, this is one way. In my case, the higher nibble of any element is always 0. So i "memset" the array with 0xff and then used the for loop. However, this becomes a solution for special case, not for cases in which any value between 00 and ff can be an element of the array !!

Answer (score 2):

If you define an element as "anything except 0x00" then a for loop will do it.

```
int len = sizeof (some_array) / sizeof (some_array[0]);
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < len; i++)
{
    if (some_array[i] != 0x00) count++;
}
/* count is now the number of non 0 elements */
```

Based on your comment it looks like you have a 30 element array but only populate the first 15 and want 15 as "the answer". The array still has 30 elements, no way (that I know of) to determine from the array that you only put 15 values into it.

Comment: This implementation will give me count as 14, whereas the number of elements are actually 15!!

Comment: And why do you make that assumption?

Comment: Because count will not increment when the element is 0 (in my case, the element with index 5)

Comment: I think @KeithThompson was commenting on a comment I've since deleted. There are plenty of answers here to choose from, but the general answer is "you can't do what you want" - the array has 30 elements even if you only put 15 in it - the others still exist and you can't tell them apart from the ones you did set.

Comment: Got it!! I have implemented a temporary solution for now using @Sumit Trehan 's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The number of elements in the array is 30.

If you want to know the number of elements to which you've assigned values, you'll have to keep track explicitly. There's no way to distinguish between an array element with some assigned value, and an uninitialized element whose (garbage) value happens to be that same value.

Comment: This is the only answer to his question with how he has worded it. I think he should be using some sort of resizeable container or declare the array with size at initialization.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. I used a count to keep track of number of elements while filling my array. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in C construct to do what you are asking.

As you said, C can tell you how large you've allocated the array to be. However, it has no concept of when you store a meaningful value in the array. When you declare the array, it has 30 (probably garbage-valued) elements in it, and when you put some of your own values in it, it still has 30 elements, some of which are your values and some of which are garbage.

`strlen()` works on [strings](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Arrays-as-Strings), a special type of `char` array in C which stores a null byte to mark the end of the string.

Comment: Yes, it is that same "NULL" byte i.e. 0 that is giving me trouble.

Comment: Right, but the larger point is that C arrays do not keep track of how many of their elements you have assigned. You'll have to do this yourself.

Answer (score 2):

define macro like this:

```
#define INITIALIZE_LIST {0xFB, 0x07, 0x0B, 0x02, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x03, 0x08, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x07, 0x0A, 0x09, 0x06, 0x0D}
#define INITIALIZE_LIST_SIZE sizeof((unsigned char[])INITIALIZE_LIST)
```

sample code to use :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define INITIALIZE_LIST {0xFB, 0x07, 0x0B, 0x02, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x03, 0x08, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x07, 0x0A, 0x09, 0x06, 0x0D}
#define INITIALIZE_LIST_SIZE sizeof((unsigned char[])INITIALIZE_LIST)

int main(void){
    unsigned char some_array[30] = INITIALIZE_LIST;
    size_t size = INITIALIZE_LIST_SIZE;
    printf("Number of initialize list is %zu\n", size);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("%02X ", some_array[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C there is no in build function to find number of elements stored in an array, because all unfilled fields in  array will have some value. It can only able to find total size of array.

One way to do this is to fill entire array with a predefined special character before loading values to array (which do not include special character). For example;

```
unsigned char some_array[30];

memcpy(some_array, '\0', 30);

Then load some values to array;

strlen(some_array);
```

Here `strlen(some_array);` will return number of characters in array

Comment: Tried doing this. strlen gives incorrect result if one of the element happens to be 0. (Already mentioned this in my question!!).

Comment: are you storing non-character values (like integers) in the array?

Comment: you are asking this so that i can do "memcpy(some_array, 'some non-character value', 30);", and then fill the array and count upto this some non-character value, right !! Well, i am storing values between 0x00 to 0xFF.