# How can I read data from an array if the array size is too large.....!

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

How can I read only that cells those are containing data values from this following array.
[sample array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAQEp.png)

Here is my code as an example which is displaying the values but its reading all the cells for retrieve only 4 values. How can I avoid this zero containing locations?.There might be data in random locations and rest of the locations will be zero.So is there any way to read only the data value containing cells.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int i,data[500000]={25,0,0,0,0,98,0,0,13,0,857};
    for(i=0;i<500000;i++)
    {
        if(data[i]==0)
            continue;
        printf("%d\t",data[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code says not to print zeros. Only four of the values in the array are non-zero. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Also why are you using `500000` when you're only initialising with 11 values?

Comment: If you need an array of half a million `int` values, the stack is probably not the best place for it. Use `malloc()` or `calloc()` instead.

Comment: Fill the array with a sentinel value, like -1 and when you hit that, break out of your loop. If the valid numbers don't allow for a sentinel value then you'll just have to keep track of how much of the array you're using another way.

Comment: The only way to display only the cells containing values is to loop over all of them, what you are doing more or less

Comment: What is the problem? It looks like your code does exactly what you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36905534/971127

Comment: I hope whoever upvoted this question can explain what exactly it tries to ask.

Comment: @humayun Consider adding "My code spends time examining `data[11]` through to `data[500000]`, unnecessarily. How can I avoid this unnecessary work?" -- if that accurately reflects your question. The question might then get reopened.

Comment: Thank you  @slim...!! Array size 500000 was an example....Yes my question is How can I avoid this unnecessary work?......There might be data in random locations and rest of the locations will be zero....so how can i avoid this zero if the array size is too big.

Comment: Don't clarify in comments - edit the question until it is clear. Otherwise it will remain closed. But if you're going to have valid data scattered randomly around the large array, and no indexing mechanism, you'll have to look in each element. But why would you store data like that?

Comment: If the array location itself is a index of that data then it will be possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I think I understand the question now. I think you want to know how you could stop reading after `data[10]` because although you've allocated half a million entries, right now nowhere near all those elements are populated.

Note that we're assuming our own meaning of "populated". C has no concept of an empty array element.

In C it's quite common to keep a `size` variable alongside oversized arrays. So you could do something similar to:

```
int data[500000]={25,0,0,0,0,98,0,0,13,0,857};
int size = 11;
for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    if(data[i]==0) {
        continue;
    }
    printf("%d\t",data[i]);
}
```

(I've added braces to your `if` block - don't get in the habit of omitting them)

You seem to want to skip zeros, I've left that in.

When you add an element, you'll need to increment size.

```
data[size] = newValue;
size++;
```

... or in terser idiomatic C ...

```
data[size++] = newValue;
```

... and you'll need to make sure that whatever works with your array, also sees the length. For example, you can't have a function `findHighest(int data[])` --
 it'll have to be `findHighest(int data[], int size`. As you progress in your C studies, you'll find how a `struct` helps you achieve this more neatly.

An example of this in action is the `read` system call:

```
int length = read(file, buf, count);
```

`buf` is a `char[]` of a length <= `count`. `read()` will read some number of bytes up to `count`, and return `length`. `buf[0]` through to `buf[length-1]` contain the bytes you want to work with. `buf[length]` onward is junk.

---

An alternative is to ensure that the first irrelevant value in the array contains a *sentinel value* indicating "no more to see". For example you could use `-1`, if you're sure that will never be a valid value. A very simple approach is to fill the array with `-1`s at initialisation time (use `memset()`). Alternatively make sure you write a sentinel value at `data[index_of_last_value + 1]` whenever you extend the length.

The standard C string handling functions are examples of code that uses a sentinel. `NULL` (zero, `'\0'`) indicates the end of a string, which is very often stored in a longer buffer.